# Diagram Tools in statechart does not show all tools rational Rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

I am learning Rational Rhapsody C++ 8.3 and could not able to find some tools like  History connector diagram connector  junction connector etc. I can see termination connector condition connector etc. Can some one please guide what changes i Need to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your model is currently using the "basic" perspective, which hides options that are considered more advanced.

[Perspective toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHHLB.png)

Go to the Perspective toolbar and change the setting to "advanced" and see if the missing tools are now visible.

Comment: yday all night I was fiddling around with project properties  and chaning general :: graphics etc but no joy. I undo all changes and did what you suggested and it works. Thanks a ton